# How to completely remove kwin?

Tags: login, uninstall, screen, kwin

I installed kwin yesterday, using this command:
sudo atp-get install kde-window-manager

then I thought it didnt work, so I also did this command, then rebooted
sudo apt-get install kde-workspace-bin

now it did work.

However I really want to remove it because I lack disk space.
How do I completely remove kwin, to ubuntu basics.
So that the login screen is back to the original ubuntu login screen and I have more freed disk space.

I tried 
sudo atp-get remove kde-window-manager
and
sudo apt-get remove kde-workspace-bin

the login screen is still different from the original ubuntu login screen, and I gained a mere ~12mb disk space instead of ~110mb used for kwin.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge <package>` should do it.

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you using?

Comment: Precise Pangolin Ubunbtu 12.04

Comment: Jonathan - you appear to have two accounts.  Please click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page and request that your accounts are merged.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All packages installed as a result of being dependencies of the ones you have installed manually, are still marked as installed automatically. Run

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

to remove the packages not listed as "required" anymore on your system.

So, basically, let's say that the installation of `package-a` requires `package-b`, then removing `package-a` does not remove `package-b` as well. By running `apt-get autoremove`, it will notice that there's no requrement anymore for `package-b` and it will offer to remove it.

---

> the login screen is still different from the original ubuntu login screen

That's probably because you pulled in `kdm`, the KDE display manager and login screen. Remove it as well if the previous command didn't do that already:

```
sudo apt-get remove kdm
```